# Adapt label width to text

Tags: vba, excel

I basically programmatically generate many labels with a text read from a text file so I would like to know how I can programmatically adapt the width of a Label to its text.

Comment: This is easiest if is the font is monospaced. Look up how to change a label's width first, then how to find the size of a text according to size of said text second.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Controls come in two flavors. The ActiveX version of a label has an `AutoSize` property. For example, with a ActiveX label control named `Label1` in `Sheet1`

```
Private Sub test()
    Sheet1.Label1.WordWrap = False
    Sheet1.Label1.AutoSize = True
    Sheet1.Label1.Caption = "This is a lot of text to put in a label"
End Sub
```

will automatically adjust the width to fit.